# rainbow-delimiters does not properly highlight unmatched parenthesis

Tags: balanced-parentheses, parentheses

Would it be possible to highlight unmatched parenthesis if they are at the beginning of a function like `func((((()`?

Related:
[How can I find missing or mismatched braces / parens in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319712/how-can-i-find-missing-or-mismatched-braces-parens-in-emacs)

**minimal.el**    //example is taken from the link above

```
(require 'package)
(setq user-init-file (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
(setq user-emacs-directory (file-name-directory user-init-file))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(set-face-attribute 'rainbow-delimiters-unmatched-face nil
            :foreground "red"
            :background "yellow"
            :inherit 'error
            :box t)
```

It find unmatcing parenthesis for `print("Hello"))` when parenthesis at the end.
Find error:
[image]

But it does not do anything for if unmatched parenthesis are at the beginning: `print(((((((((((((((((("Hello")`

[image]

Comment: If you feel there's a problem with rainbow-delimiters, or you want to submit an enhancement request, please contact the package maintainer. The question part of your question seems unclear.

Comment: Define *"unmatched parenthesis if they are at the beginning"*. Who or what is to say that the problem is too many parens at the beginning, and not too few at the end?

Comment: Its enhancement but https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowParenMode does not detect it as well. `too many parens at the beginning, and not too few at the end` yes sir // I have opened an issue on their repo: https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters/issues/62

Comment: @Drew Please see my answer that was only solution I was able to come up with my basic knowledge. Rainbow guys told me that its not easy so I was not able to get any help from them. The only problem in `check-parens` does not alert where its message in minibuffer get hidden after a second in any mismatched parenthesis. I wish  I was able to keep its message longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue:](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters/issues/62#issuecomment-901090024)

> Not easily, no. In the worst case it would require going through the
> entire buffer to determine that an opening parenthesis has no matching
> closing one, which is slow and doesn't play well with how font-lock
> works.

---

My goal was to detect any mismatching parenthesis in `python-mode`. The only smart way I come up was to do `check-parens` after each save. It jumps the mismatched parenthesis in the buffer.

I have following function:

```lisp
(defun save-all ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((message-log-max nil)
        (inhibit-message t))
    (save-some-buffers t)
    (check-parens)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'save-all)

;; could be set for a specific mode
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-s") 'save-all-check-paren)
```